# displaying mongodb documents in nested form without changing in database

Tags: mongodb, go

I've a certain list of mongodb documents with parent reference but it is not nested.
I want to display it in nested form without changing in database. The Documents are connected through single column "parent" which is in string type. I'm using golang for retrieving data.

```
type Category struct {
   UID        primitive.ObjectID    
   CategoryID string        
   Parent     string             
   Title      string
}
```

The uid of the single category is the parent to its sub categories.
How can I display it in nested form on basis of parent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to relate documents from different collections, if that's what you are looking for, you can try the aggregation.
With aggregation you can get documents from different collections and put inside your result, but you need equal field values.

```
cursor, err := parentCollection.Aggregate(context, []bson.M{
            {"$lookup": {                  // $lookup operator to get document from other collection
                "from": "CategoryCollection",
                "localField": "Parent string",
                "foreignField": "Parent string",
                "as": "Category"
            }},
{
            "$match": {     //$match operator to select the Parent you need
                "ParentId": {
                    "id": "parentId"  // If you need only selected parent
                }
            }
        }
        })
```